# error with importing sage into a python file

Tags: python, django, environment-variables, ubuntu-16.04, sage

Im trying to import a sage package (var) in a python file

```
from sage.all import var
```

but when run the file Im getting this error :

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):

    execfile("/home/sagefolder/SageMath/myapp/core/test.py")
  File "/home/sagefolder/SageMath/ubbr/engine/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    from sage.all import var
  File "/home/sagefolder/SageMath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/all.py", line 71, in <module>
    from sage.env import SAGE_ROOT, SAGE_SRC, SAGE_DOC_SRC, SAGE_LOCAL, DOT_SAGE, SAGE_ENV
  File "/home/sagefolder/SageMath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/env.py", line 123, in <module>
    _add_variable_or_fallback('SAGE_ETC',        opj('$SAGE_LOCAL', 'etc'))
  File "/home/sagefolder/SageMath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/env.py", line 103, in _add_variable_or_fallback
    value = sep.join(components)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found
```

my guess was that the problems was related to the env path. but even

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/the/sage/')
```

it does not work

It seems it has problem with the value of some env variables like 'SAGE_ROOT' and ... but according to the [installation manual](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/binary.html#sec-installation-from-binaries), if I set the symbolic link

`ln -s /path/to/SageMath/sage /usr/local/bin/sage`

then all the required env variable are automatically handled.

this module is called from a django views.py which is also installed as a Sage package. if I run the the module 
using

```
sage test.py
```

everything is ok but when it is called from a django view which is also installed as sage packages I got the mentioned error

I would be pleased if anybody can help me as Im doing an important project and I really need to use sage.

Comment: You're not getting an `ImportError`, so I don't think this is a path problem.  Have you set the required Sage environment variables?

Comment: @JohnGordon. can you explain more how can I do this?  according to the installation guide . https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/binary.html#linux-and-os-x .  It's only need to create the hard link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the env variables in the python file which is called from djagno views function. and it's solved. you need to set the following variables:

```
import os
os.environ['SAGE_ROOT'] = 'you can find this path by running os.environ['SAGE_ROOT'] in sage shell 
os.environ['SAGE_SRC'] = 'you can find this path by running os.environ['SAGE_ROOT'] in sage shell 
os.environ['SAGE_DOC_SRC'] = 'you can find this path by running os.environ['SAGE_ROOT'] in sage shell 
os.environ['SAGE_LOCAL'] = 'you can find this path by running os.environ['SAGE_ROOT'] in sage shell 
os.environ['DOT_SAGE'] = 'you can find this path by running os.environ['SAGE_ROOT'] in sage shell
```